# How to run method before others?

Tags: php

I need to run one private method before some others public methods, so i used `__call` method which seems to override default method calling so it looks like this

```
function __call($method, $arguments)
{
    // echo($method);

    if (in_array($method, array('changeStatus', 'lockStatus'))) 
        $this->_checkInputData($arguments);

    call_user_func($method, $arguments);
}
```

But i'm suddenly noticed that `__call` method works only on non-defined methods, so is there any way to call custom method before specified?

Comment: why don't you call this method in your public method?

Comment: Call the methods manually at the top of the public methods.

Comment: i can't do it because user specifies it by himself

Comment: Specifies what? Be more specific.

Comment: If you need to call a private method first, why not call it from the constructor?

Comment: `__call` is only invoked for *non accessible/existing* methods. You'll have to restructure what you're doing, you can't hook into *every* public function call.

Comment: If the user needs to be able to call methods then those methods should be protected (so they can be accessed by an extending class) or public.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit odd. To call private method before public you can call it in your public method example

```
class Example
{
   private function methodA()
   {
     echo 'I am a method A';
   }

   public function methodB()
   {
     $this->methodA();
     echo 'I am a method B';
   }
}
```

in that way when you call methodB on object it will call firstly methodA and then body of method B.

**Edit**

you wanted to specify what method should be called.

```
class Example
{
   private function methodA()
   {
     echo 'I am a method A';
   }

   private function methodB()
   {
     echo 'I am a method B';
   }

   public function callMethods($method)
   {
      if($method =='a') $this->methodA();
      else if($method =='b') $this->methodA();
      //rest of function  
   }
}
```

In this way you can specify in

```
$obj = new Example();
$obj->callMethods('a'); // will call firstly MethodA
$obj->callMethods('b'); // will call firstly MethodB
```

Comment: as i said - user chooses by himself which methods should be checked.

Comment: give your code because it's not known what exactly you want to do, maybe it can be done in different way.

Comment: ie means different function for different options